# How do I select distinct customers who have both attributes 'S' and 'P' in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

In a SQL table I have two fields among many others: CustomerID and TransactionType.  CustomerID is a unique number that can be repeated with each transaction.  Each transaction is either 'S' or 'P'.

[image]

I want to select the distinct customerIDs that have both 'S' and 'P' in SQL. So in the table above my expected return values are 100 and 102. How can I do this?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation for this:

```
select customerid
from your_table
where transactionType in ('S', 'P')
group by customerid
having count(distinct transactionType) = 2;
```

You can lose the where clause if the transaction type can only be 'S' or 'P' (not even null).

Comment: Thank You!  This makes sense!